# How to remove the value for text field/text_area field

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have 2 text field (1 text field and another 1 text area field)

If user enters the input into the (#accession_number) text field, then suddenly realized it's the wrong field, they would have to click the #FASTA_p to show (#FASTA) text area field and hide (#accession_number) field.

Problem :
The values of (#accession number) is still there even after clicking hide . How should i totally remove the input user entered ?

For example:
I chosed the wrong field and input my values but I haven't click submit. I realized i entered in the wrong field, so i clicked another field to enter my input but at the same time i want to remove the values in the first field. How should i do that besdie asking user to do it manually?[image]

Answer (score 1):

you could simply do

```
$("#FSTA").show().val($("#accession_number").val())
$("#accession_number").hide().val("")
```

Comment: The values still appear in the accession number field when i click back .

Comment: what does your 'back' button do?

Comment: back button ? i don't have back button

Comment: please explane me better your problem

Comment: In this page i have 2 text field. If i entered the input to the first text field, the moment i clicked them, the 2nd text_area field will be hidden. Before clicking submit, i realized im not suppose to use text field  but text_area field without erasing the content in text field. The program should accept the field that's shown. So in this case the text_area . But my now my program is not turning the text_field null . Both text_field and text_area field has values even though one of them is hidden and tried all those suggesttions they suggested above

Comment: my code should do the job. Be sure your element ID is unique in the dom

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default text value as follows,

`$('#accession_number').prop( 'defaultValue' );`

Have a look http://jsfiddle.net/kHBsD/8/